# Java: Oracle example code not running: "NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to learn how to set up a GUI layout, so I'm reading through [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), which has [this example code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java).

The problem is, when I run the code (either through Geany or the command line), it seems to compile correctly, then it gives me this error when I try to run it:

[image: NoClassDefFoundError]

Since this is a sample from Oracle, I am working under the assumption that I am not running the program correctly, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GridBagLayoutDemo.java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/GridBagLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java) is declared to be in the package `layout`, but you placed it in the default package (no subdirectory). So either remove the `package` statement, or move the file in a directory called `layout` and then call `javac layout/GridBagLayoutDemo.java && java layout.GridBagLayoutDemo`.